# Blazor + conditional HTML Comments

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

In a Blazor Server app, I'm trying to generate HTML which will be rendered for consumption in an email.

Meaning, the server will generate the full HTML based on a template which I will merge with various bits of data.

One of the things I'd like to do is include some conditional HTML so it renders well in Outlook, some of what I'm trying to do is described here: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/139/all-you-need-to-know-about-conditional-html-comments

When I include any html comments, Blazor's rendering engine ignores them and does not include them in the output.

Is there some way to force Blazor's renderer to include my comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need MarkupString

```
@((MarkupString)"<!-- test -->")
```

or

```
@code
{
    MarkupString comment = new MarkupString("<!-- test2 -->");
}
@comment
```